# How to run Wilcox test on all combination of groups across large number of features in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, statistics, memory-efficient

I have a large sparse matrix (lets call it `matrix`) in which the rows are the features and the columns are the samples. Each column/sample belong to 1 of 6 groups. I randomly sample some amount from each group and store what index they belong to in the original matrix.

```
astro_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[1] 
endo_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[2] 
micro_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[3]
neuron_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[4] 
oligo_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[5] 
opc_index <- Map(sample,row_index, num_sample)[6]
```

The goal is to be able perform a Wilcox test and get the p-value on all the combination of the 6 groups for each features. The big issue is that I have over 30,000 features to test on all combination of 6 groups (so that is 15 comparisons for each of the 30,000+ features).

So I have two current methods. The **first** one uses the apply function and does it for only one comparison (here astro and neuron group). The disadvantage for this method is that I run into memory issues and it only does 1 comparison at a time. I would have to write this 14 more times to get all possible comparisons.

```
store_p <- apply(matrix,1,function(x) {wilcox.test(x[astro_index],x[neuron_index])$p.value })
```

The **second** method uses a for loop to go through all the features but I take advantage of the combn and the data frame to calculate the p-value for all combinations but one feature at a time. This method is really slow but does not crash.

```
for (i in features){

  df <- data.frame('Astro' = matrix[i,astro_index], 'Endo' = matrix[i,endo_index], 'Micro' = matrix[i,micro_index], 'Neuron' = matrix[i,neuron_index], 'Oligo' = matrix[i,oligo_index], 'OPC' = matrix[i,opc_index])
  result <- combn(names(df), 2, FUN = function(x) paste(paste(x, collapse='-'), wilcox.test(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]], paired = TRUE)$p.value, sep=" : ")) 
  hold_list <- append(hold_list, list(result))

}
```

To give a sense of what the `result` looks like. Here is a sample output of `result`

```
> result
 [1] "Astro-Endo : 0.115331575924872"      "Astro-Micro : 0.935664046257304"     "Astro-Neuron : 0.0271849565394441"  
 [4] "Astro-Oligo : 0.00147694402781699"   "Astro-OPC : 0.0476580762532988"      "Endo-Micro : 0.297672151508384"     
 [7] "Endo-Neuron : 2.38134038927696e-06"  "Endo-Oligo : 0.0323129112432441"     "Endo-OPC : 0.451258974150342"       
[10] "Micro-Neuron : 0.000143621746738224" "Micro-Oligo : 0.0178171887595787"    "Micro-OPC : 0.0692129715131915"     
[13] "Neuron-Oligo : 6.68255453156116e-10" "Neuron-OPC : 6.201108273594e-07"     "Oligo-OPC : 0.142213241936393"
```

I would ideally like the best of both world of both methods and do a more efficient process to compute these tests. Also if there is a suggestion to designing a different data frame all together to tackle this task in one way I would appreciate that too.

**EDIT**
I realized I did not make at as clear but the `result` is only for one feature of all combinations. I have a for loop so that it goes through all the features. In essence, there should be a p-value calculated for all the feature and for all the combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pairwiseWilcox` from `scran` for that - that seems ideally suited for your problem.
It performs pairwise Wilcoxon rank sum tests for each row between groups of columns, where groups is a vector of column assignments.

**Edit:**

- Sampled groups to have equal number of elements (columns), since the OP seems to want that.
- Made the matrix less sparse to make it clearer that it does not compare individual values, but groups of values for each row.

Example:

```r
library(Matrix)
types <- c("Astro", "Neuron", "Endo", "Oligo", "OPC", "Micro")

# generate sparse matrix
set.seed(123)
mat <- Matrix(0, nrow = 10000, ncol = 1000, sparse = TRUE)
mat[sample(seq_along(mat), 1E5)] <- runif(n = 1e5, min = 0, max=100)
groups <- c(rep(types, each = floor(ncol(mat)/6)), rep("Micro", ncol(mat) %% 6))
colnames(mat) <- make.unique(groups)

# sample n=100 samples of each group
idx <- setNames(lapply(types, function(x) grep(x, colnames(mat))), types)
smp <- Map(sample, idx, size = 100)
groups <- gsub("[0-9]+", "", names(unlist(smp)))

# subset mat to sampled columns
mat <- mat[, unlist(smp, use.names = FALSE)]

library(scran)

pwt <- pairwiseWilcox(mat, groups = groups)
pwt
#> $statistics
#> $statistics[[1]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.51000  0.158341  0.616668
#> 3       0.49000  0.158341  0.616668
#> 4       0.50490  0.573540  0.856541
#> 5       0.48985  0.308851  0.616668
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4950  0.565662  0.856541
#> 9997     0.5050  0.322174  0.616668
#> 9998     0.4951  0.573540  0.856541
#> 9999     0.4950  0.322174  0.616668
#> 10000    0.5050  0.322174  0.616668
#> 
#> $statistics[[2]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5050 0.3221741  0.613045
#> 2        0.5049 0.5735395  0.858464
#> 3        0.4800 0.0444225  0.613045
#> 4        0.4947 0.6352736  0.948311
#> 5        0.4949 0.5578376  0.858464
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49500  0.565662  0.858464
#> 9997    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.50500  0.322174  0.613045
#> 9999    0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.50500  0.322174  0.613045
#> 
#> $statistics[[3]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5050  0.322174  0.605697
#> 2        0.5001  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.5100  0.158341  0.605697
#> 5        0.4949  0.557838  0.854499
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.49500  0.322174  0.605697
#> 10000   0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[4]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.50010  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3       0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4       0.49490  0.648212  0.959177
#> 5       0.50500  0.322174  0.615026
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4949  0.557838  0.859750
#> 9997     0.4951  0.573540  0.859750
#> 9998     0.4852  0.182661  0.615026
#> 9999     0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000    0.4949  0.557838  0.859750
#> 
#> $statistics[[5]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 2       0.49480  0.641729  0.964426
#> 3       0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4       0.51000  0.158341  0.620334
#> 5       0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.49015  0.323442  0.620334
#> 9998    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.49500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 10000   0.50500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 
#> $statistics[[6]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.49000  0.158341  0.616668
#> 3       0.51000  0.158341  0.616668
#> 4       0.49510  0.573540  0.856541
#> 5       0.51015  0.308851  0.616668
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5050  0.565662  0.856541
#> 9997     0.4950  0.322174  0.616668
#> 9998     0.5049  0.573540  0.856541
#> 9999     0.5050  0.322174  0.616668
#> 10000    0.4950  0.322174  0.616668
#> 
#> $statistics[[7]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50500  0.322174  0.616668
#> 2       0.49500  0.322174  0.616668
#> 3       0.48960  0.392127  0.746909
#> 4       0.49005  0.318530  0.616668
#> 5       0.50500  0.654721  0.960283
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5001  0.995980  1.000000
#> 9997     0.4950  0.322174  0.616668
#> 9998     0.5100  0.158341  0.616668
#> 9999     0.5050  0.322174  0.616668
#> 10000    0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[8]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1         0.505  0.322174  0.604226
#> 2         0.490  0.158341  0.604226
#> 3         0.510  0.158341  0.604226
#> 4         0.505  0.322174  0.604226
#> 5         0.505  0.654721  0.952044
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50510  0.557838  0.849437
#> 9997    0.49500  0.322174  0.604226
#> 9998    0.50500  0.565662  0.849437
#> 9999    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.49500  0.322174  0.604226
#> 
#> $statistics[[9]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.49000  0.158341  0.611076
#> 3       0.51000  0.158341  0.611076
#> 4       0.49005  0.318530  0.611076
#> 5       0.51500  0.082748  0.611076
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997     0.4900  0.158341  0.611076
#> 9998     0.4899  0.405995  0.762863
#> 9999     0.5050  0.322174  0.611076
#> 10000    0.4900  0.158341  0.611076
#> 
#> $statistics[[10]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50500  0.322174  0.619147
#> 2       0.48500  0.082748  0.619147
#> 3       0.51000  0.158341  0.619147
#> 4       0.50500  0.322174  0.619147
#> 5       0.50985  0.323442  0.619147
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50500  0.565662  0.863244
#> 9997    0.48500  0.082748  0.619147
#> 9998    0.50510  0.557838  0.863244
#> 9999    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[11]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.4950 0.3221741  0.613045
#> 2        0.4951 0.5735395  0.858464
#> 3        0.5200 0.0444225  0.613045
#> 4        0.5053 0.6352736  0.948311
#> 5        0.5051 0.5578376  0.858464
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50500  0.565662  0.858464
#> 9997    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.49500  0.322174  0.613045
#> 9999    0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.49500  0.322174  0.613045
#> 
#> $statistics[[12]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49500  0.322174  0.616668
#> 2       0.50500  0.322174  0.616668
#> 3       0.51040  0.392127  0.746909
#> 4       0.50995  0.318530  0.616668
#> 5       0.49500  0.654721  0.960283
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4999  0.995980  1.000000
#> 9997     0.5050  0.322174  0.616668
#> 9998     0.4900  0.158341  0.616668
#> 9999     0.4950  0.322174  0.616668
#> 10000    0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[13]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 2        0.4951 0.5735395  0.868341
#> 3        0.5200 0.0444225  0.625009
#> 4        0.5150 0.0827480  0.625009
#> 5        0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50500  0.565662  0.868341
#> 9997    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.49500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 9999    0.49500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 10000   0.49500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 
#> $statistics[[14]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49500 0.3221741  0.606038
#> 2       0.49510 0.5735395  0.852213
#> 3       0.52000 0.0444225  0.606038
#> 4       0.50005 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 5       0.51000 0.1583409  0.606038
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4998 0.9879417  1.000000
#> 9997     0.4951 0.5735395  0.852213
#> 9998     0.4800 0.0444225  0.606038
#> 9999     0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 10000    0.4900 0.1583409  0.606038
#> 
#> $statistics[[15]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.49005 0.3185296  0.619978
#> 3       0.52000 0.0444225  0.619978
#> 4       0.51500 0.0827480  0.619978
#> 5       0.50500 0.5656624  0.863114
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50500  0.565662  0.863114
#> 9997    0.49015  0.323442  0.619978
#> 9998    0.49500  0.322174  0.619978
#> 9999    0.49500  0.322174  0.619978
#> 10000   0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[16]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.4950  0.322174  0.605697
#> 2        0.4999  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.4900  0.158341  0.605697
#> 5        0.5051  0.557838  0.854499
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.50500  0.322174  0.605697
#> 10000   0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[17]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1         0.495  0.322174  0.604226
#> 2         0.510  0.158341  0.604226
#> 3         0.490  0.158341  0.604226
#> 4         0.495  0.322174  0.604226
#> 5         0.495  0.654721  0.952044
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49490  0.557838  0.849437
#> 9997    0.50500  0.322174  0.604226
#> 9998    0.49500  0.565662  0.849437
#> 9999    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.50500  0.322174  0.604226
#> 
#> $statistics[[18]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 2        0.5049 0.5735395  0.868341
#> 3        0.4800 0.0444225  0.625009
#> 4        0.4850 0.0827480  0.625009
#> 5        0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49500  0.565662  0.868341
#> 9997    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9998    0.50500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 9999    0.50500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 10000   0.50500  0.322174  0.625009
#> 
#> $statistics[[19]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.4950  0.322174  0.619978
#> 2        0.4999  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.4850  0.082748  0.619978
#> 5        0.5100  0.158341  0.619978
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4949  0.557838  0.863504
#> 9997     0.4951  0.573540  0.863504
#> 9998     0.4850  0.176800  0.619978
#> 9999     0.5050  0.322174  0.619978
#> 10000    0.4949  0.557838  0.863504
#> 
#> $statistics[[20]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2        0.4947  0.635274  0.958759
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 5        0.5050  0.565662  0.869131
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.49015  0.323442  0.625372
#> 9998    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.50500  0.322174  0.625372
#> 
#> $statistics[[21]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.49990  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3       0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4       0.50510  0.648212  0.959177
#> 5       0.49500  0.322174  0.615026
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5051  0.557838  0.859750
#> 9997     0.5049  0.573540  0.859750
#> 9998     0.5148  0.182661  0.615026
#> 9999     0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000    0.5051  0.557838  0.859750
#> 
#> $statistics[[22]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.51000  0.158341  0.611076
#> 3       0.49000  0.158341  0.611076
#> 4       0.50995  0.318530  0.611076
#> 5       0.48500  0.082748  0.611076
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997     0.5100  0.158341  0.611076
#> 9998     0.5101  0.405995  0.762863
#> 9999     0.4950  0.322174  0.611076
#> 10000    0.5100  0.158341  0.611076
#> 
#> $statistics[[23]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50500 0.3221741  0.606038
#> 2       0.50490 0.5735395  0.852213
#> 3       0.48000 0.0444225  0.606038
#> 4       0.49995 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 5       0.49000 0.1583409  0.606038
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5002 0.9879417  1.000000
#> 9997     0.5049 0.5735395  0.852213
#> 9998     0.5200 0.0444225  0.606038
#> 9999     0.5000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 10000    0.5100 0.1583409  0.606038
#> 
#> $statistics[[24]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5050  0.322174  0.619978
#> 2        0.5001  0.995980  1.000000
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.5150  0.082748  0.619978
#> 5        0.4900  0.158341  0.619978
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5051  0.557838  0.863504
#> 9997     0.5049  0.573540  0.863504
#> 9998     0.5150  0.176800  0.619978
#> 9999     0.4950  0.322174  0.619978
#> 10000    0.5051  0.557838  0.863504
#> 
#> $statistics[[25]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5050  0.322174  0.618555
#> 2        0.4947  0.635274  0.954724
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.5150  0.082748  0.618555
#> 5        0.4950  0.322174  0.618555
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.5051  0.557838  0.864937
#> 9997     0.4948  0.641729  0.961248
#> 9998     0.5152  0.171079  0.618555
#> 9999     0.4950  0.322174  0.618555
#> 10000    0.5100  0.158341  0.618555
#> 
#> $statistics[[26]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 2       0.50520  0.641729  0.964426
#> 3       0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4       0.49000  0.158341  0.620334
#> 5       0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.50985  0.323442  0.620334
#> 9998    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.50500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 10000   0.49500  0.322174  0.620334
#> 
#> $statistics[[27]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.49500  0.322174  0.619147
#> 2       0.51500  0.082748  0.619147
#> 3       0.49000  0.158341  0.619147
#> 4       0.49500  0.322174  0.619147
#> 5       0.49015  0.323442  0.619147
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49500  0.565662  0.863244
#> 9997    0.51500  0.082748  0.619147
#> 9998    0.49490  0.557838  0.863244
#> 9999    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[28]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1       0.50000 1.0000000  1.000000
#> 2       0.50995 0.3185296  0.619978
#> 3       0.48000 0.0444225  0.619978
#> 4       0.48500 0.0827480  0.619978
#> 5       0.49500 0.5656624  0.863114
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.49500  0.565662  0.863114
#> 9997    0.50985  0.323442  0.619978
#> 9998    0.50500  0.322174  0.619978
#> 9999    0.50500  0.322174  0.619978
#> 10000   0.50000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 
#> $statistics[[29]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 2        0.5053  0.635274  0.958759
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 5        0.4950  0.565662  0.869131
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996    0.50005  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9997    0.50985  0.323442  0.625372
#> 9998    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 9999    0.49995  1.000000  1.000000
#> 10000   0.49500  0.322174  0.625372
#> 
#> $statistics[[30]]
#> DataFrame with 10000 rows and 3 columns
#>             AUC   p.value       FDR
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
#> 1        0.4950  0.322174  0.618555
#> 2        0.5053  0.635274  0.954724
#> 3        0.5000  1.000000  1.000000
#> 4        0.4850  0.082748  0.618555
#> 5        0.5050  0.322174  0.618555
#> ...         ...       ...       ...
#> 9996     0.4949  0.557838  0.864937
#> 9997     0.5052  0.641729  0.961248
#> 9998     0.4848  0.171079  0.618555
#> 9999     0.5050  0.322174  0.618555
#> 10000    0.4900  0.158341  0.618555
#> 
#> 
#> $pairs
#> DataFrame with 30 rows and 2 columns
#>           first      second
#>     <character> <character>
#> 1         Astro        Endo
#> 2         Astro       Micro
#> 3         Astro      Neuron
#> 4         Astro       Oligo
#> 5         Astro         OPC
#> ...         ...         ...
#> 26          OPC       Astro
#> 27          OPC        Endo
#> 28          OPC       Micro
#> 29          OPC      Neuron
#> 30          OPC       Oligo
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit #2:**

Just to see what my approach would give you in about 1/20,000th of time (on my machine, at least) of the approach by StupidWolf, try this with his example `mat` and `group`:

```r
set.seed(111)
celltypes = c("astro","endo","micro","neuron","oligo","opc")
mat = matrix(rnorm(10000*120),ncol=120)
colnames(mat) = paste0("cell",1:120)
rownames(mat) = paste0("gene",1:10000)
metadata = data.frame(celltype=rep(celltypes,each=20))
num_sample = 10
use_cols = tapply(1:nrow(metadata),metadata$celltype,sample,num_sample)
use_cols = unlist(use_cols)
group = metadata$celltype[use_cols]

library(scran)
library(data.table)
pwt <- pairwiseWilcox(mat[,use_cols], groups=group)
unique_comps <- !duplicated(t(apply(pwt$pairs, 1, sort)))
res <- rbindlist(setNames(lapply(pwt$statistics[unique_comps], 
                                 function(x) as.data.table(x, keep.rownames=TRUE)), 
                          apply(pwt$pairs[unique_comps,], 1, paste, collapse = '_')),
                 idcol = "comparison")[, .(comparison, rn, p.value)]

setnames(res, "rn", "gene")
res[gene=="gene999"]
#>       comparison    gene   p.value
#>  1:   astro_endo gene999 0.1858767
#>  2:  astro_micro gene999 0.5707504
#>  3: astro_neuron gene999 0.3846731
#>  4:  astro_oligo gene999 0.4273553
#>  5:    astro_opc gene999 0.3846731
#>  6:   endo_micro gene999 0.4726756
#>  7:  endo_neuron gene999 0.9097219
#>  8:   endo_oligo gene999 0.6231762
#>  9:     endo_opc gene999 0.6775850
#> 10: micro_neuron gene999 0.9097219
#> 11:  micro_oligo gene999 0.9097219
#> 12:    micro_opc gene999 0.9097219
#> 13: neuron_oligo gene999 0.8501067
#> 14:   neuron_opc gene999 0.6775850
#> 15:    oligo_opc gene999 0.9698500
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It is not clear to me how/what it is comparing and computing the test statistics on. This seems to be comparing each individual value in the matrix to others as opposed to pooling one feature from the 6 groups (each with some x amount of sample from the respective group) and performing the test on that, which is what I want to do.

Comment: See edited post, trying to make the point it does what it is supposed to do. Small differences come from how ties are broken.

Comment: Hey the second edit seems really promising. However, whenever I run `res` I get an error that says `Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'rn' not found`. I double checked to make sure I was using @StupidWolf `mat` and `group` variables but I still keep getting this error.

Comment: `rn` is the automatially generated column name when coercing a data.frame to a data.table using `keep.rownames=TRUE`. In the later part of the code I renamed that column to `gene`. The code should run - see full reproducible example in final edit. The second edit did nothing else than applying a different example and coercing the results lists into one big table.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the code you have doesn't make sense for people who are not familiar with this kind of data. Most likely you have a gene expression matrix and for each row (gene), you want to perform a pairwise wilcox test. You sample from the meta data, hence `row_index`.

Most likely not the best thing to do statistically, but this is one way to organize your data. First set up some data:

```
set.seed(111)

celltypes = c("astro","endo","micro","neuron","oligo","opc")
mat = matrix(rnorm(10000*120),ncol=120)
colnames(mat) = paste0("cell",1:120)
rownames(mat) = paste0("gene",1:10000)
metadata = data.frame(celltype=rep(celltypes,each=20))
```

We can efficiently sample by doing:

```
num_sample = 10
use_cols = tapply(1:nrow(metadata),metadata$celltype,sample,num_sample)
use_cols = unlist(use_cols)
group = metadata$celltype[use_cols]
```

Below you need to decide on 1. whether to use a FDR correction (which you can do afterwards), and also whether you want such a massive data.frame:

```
library(broom)
allpairs = lapply(1:nrow(mat),function(i){
result = tidy(pairwise.wilcox.test(x=mat[i,use_cols],group,
p.adjust.method ="none"))
result$gene = rownames(mat)[i]
result
})
allpairs = do.call(rbind,allpairs)
```

The above takes a while, but it should run ok, you can also consider parallelizing it. Result looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  group1 group2 p.value gene 
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1 endo   astro    0.853 gene1
2 micro  astro    0.393 gene1
3 neuron astro    0.971 gene1
4 oligo  astro    0.739 gene1
5 opc    astro    0.631 gene1
6 micro  endo     0.247 gene1

allpairs[allpairs$gene=="gene999",]
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   group1 group2 p.value gene   
   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  
 1 endo   astro    0.529 gene999
 2 micro  astro    0.481 gene999
 3 neuron astro    1     gene999
 4 oligo  astro    0.481 gene999
 5 opc    astro    0.912 gene999
 6 micro  endo     1     gene999
 7 neuron endo     0.436 gene999
 8 oligo  endo     0.684 gene999
 9 opc    endo     0.684 gene999
10 neuron micro    0.529 gene999
11 oligo  micro    0.684 gene999
12 opc    micro    0.739 gene999
13 oligo  neuron   0.481 gene999
14 opc    neuron   0.796 gene999
15 opc    oligo    0.853 gene999
```

Comment: How do you parallelize such operations? Is it something I have to write in a way or something to tell my computer specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything right, this problem boils down to calculating a similarity measure for a group of features. I would tackle it using the `proxy` library, and `proxy::dist` function, in particular. It allows one to use a custom similarity measure.

I generated a synthetic data set to illustrate the process:

```
library(proxy)
set.seed(123)

feature_df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(n = 1000^2), 1000, 1000))
names(feature_df) <- paste0("feature_", names(feature_df))

feature_set_1 <- sample(x = 1:1000, 10)
feature_set_2 <- sample(x = 1:1000, 10)
feature_set_3 <- sample(x = 1:1000, 10)
```

Next, we define our function and run it pairwise on all feature sets:

```
test_fun <- function(x,y) {wilcox.test(x,y)$p.value}

fs <- c(feature_set_1, feature_set_2, feature_set_3)  
k <- 1
dist_mat <- vector(mode="list")
for (i in seq_along(fs)){
  for (j in 1:i){
    if (i>j) {
      dist_mat[[k]] <- proxy::dist(feature_df[fs[[i]], ], feature_df[fs[[j]], ], method = test_fun, by_rows = TRUE)
      k <- k+1
    }
  }
}
```

The `dist_mat` matrices contain quantities of interest. `i` and `j` refer to feature sets. `by_rows` is used to instruct `dist` to calculate the metric row-wise.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you did was perform the test within each feature set which is not what I want to do. I wanted to do the same thing but across the different feature set. So again looking at the example I provided in `result` I have the Astro group being compared to all the different groups (Neuron, Endo, etc). In your example that would translate to the feature_set_1 being compared with feature_set_2 as well as all the "3 choose 2" combinations. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: To clarify further, all the elements of feature_set_1 would have the Wilcox test performed agains all the elements of feature_set_2. You are doing something similar but you are doing all the comparison within each of the individual "feature_sets".

Comment: It certainly works but it is a little hard to decipher when the new feature_set comparison begins and ends (I guess this could be fixed with some labeling?). But I am worried about the loops since it took a few seconds to run (I have an matrix on the order of 30,000+ by 100,000+). I know regardless it'll take a while but I'll test it out on the original dataset.

Comment: `i` and `j` are indices that run over the feature set. `j` is such that it is less than `i`. This allows for pairwise comparison without duplicate runs (i,j is the same as j,i in this context). Think about the lower triangle of a matrix. Loops are not necessarily slow as long as they are implemented properly.

Comment: Oh I just realized the way you approached the problem was incorrect. I realized I did not explain it as well as I thought and misunderstood what you did. So the method you wrote performs the test by comparing **all** the features between the various samples. I want to compare **one** feature but since each of the elements in "feature_sets" contain a value for that one feature I want to see whether that one feature is statistically different among the three "feature_sets". Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216243/discussion-between-fp1234-and-slava-kohut).